# Pygments adding whitespace to HTML inside pre

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I'm using Pygments to syntax some HTML created by the user.

Here's what I have, notice the random padding to the left.

[image]

The random space is also selectable

[image]

I'm using Ruby to render the code block with

```
= raw Pygments.highlight(block.content, lexer: 'html', :options => {:lineanchors => "line", :lineos => true})
```

And here's the styling...

```
pre {
    counter-reset: line-numbering;
    border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: inherit;
    word-wrap: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    overflow: scroll;
}

pre a::before {
    content: counter(line-numbering);
    counter-increment: line-numbering;
    padding-right: 1em; /* space after numbers */
    width: 25px;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #aaa;
    background: #eee;
    margin-right: 16px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

pre a:first-of-type::before {
    padding-top: 10px;
    @include box-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0px 1px 1px inset);
}

pre a:last-of-type::before {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

pre a:only-of-type::before {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

That's on top of a Pygments theme, I'm using Autumn, see here https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css

Bit baffled as to what's causing this mysterious white space but if anyone might know or has experienced this problem before it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet). The problem origins in Haml and solved adding this line in the initalizers.

```
Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true
```